# How to get family/types from category using Revit API?

Tags: visual-studio, revit-api, revit

I'm working on a Revit tool using visual studio. This particular tool will apply batch tags of a specific type/family. So far my tool filters through all categories in the model and lists types categories.annotation which is for tagging. The user can select one of those categories, this is where I'm stuck once I get the user to select a category how can I get families or types from that selection?

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to achieve that.

Here is a code snippet from [The Building Coder samples](https://github.com/jeremytammik/the_building_coder_samples) that filters for family instances of a specific category:

```
ElementClassFilter f1
  = new ElementClassFilter(
    typeof( FamilyInstance ) );

ElementCategoryFilter f2
  = new ElementCategoryFilter(
    BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors );

ElementCategoryFilter f3
  = new ElementCategoryFilter(
    BuiltInCategory.OST_Windows );

LogicalOrFilter f4
  = new LogicalOrFilter( f2, f3 );

LogicalAndFilter f5
  = new LogicalAndFilter( f1, f4 );

FilteredElementCollector collector
  = new FilteredElementCollector( doc );
```

You can easily adapt that or search for other code snippets in the samples to collect the family symbols instead.

Collecting the families is a bit more tricky than the symbols, since their category is not always well-defined.

That topic was recently discussed in the [Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160)